# Nested hierarchy of objects pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have an object that can have parents and children of the same object type.  Is there a standardized way of implementing this pattern?

Something like:

```
public class Nested
{
   public string Name {get; set;}

   public List<Nested> Parents {get {TODO}}
   public List<Nested> Children {get {TODO}}
}
```

Comment: Check if this link helps http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/231184/566463.aspx . Database related discussion on similar problem http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1642466-multiple-parents-tree-digraph-implementation.html and http://forums.asp.net/t/1259184.aspx/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look on the composite pattern [here](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternComposite.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

From a memory standpoint, it seems like any instance of your class will need to filter through everything recursively to figure out what the relationships are.  That's burdensome.

I would recommend just giving your class a property like this (or something more complex, depending on what you're looking to accomplish):

```
public Nested parent;
```

This would make it into a linked list.  You can separately create a method outside of the class that manages to find parents based on a limited set of parameters (e.g. FindParentsOfNestedToCertainGeneration(int numOfGenerations, Nested child) -- This will just go to child and go up the chain of parents in the "parent" property).

Comment: Carl Benson, I think the requirement is that a single node can have multiple parents. For example, organization where employee can have more than one supervisor.